# Azure DevOps rename Project email

Tags: team-foundation-server, azure-devops

Per [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/rename-project?view=azure-devops), in Azure DevOps:

> Renaming a project sends email notifications to everyone in the
> project, if there are less than 1,000 users. If there are greater than
> 1,000 users in your project, only project collection administrators
> receive email notifications.

There are only a few users under Project Settings: General: Teams:

However there are many users with permissions to the Project in  Project Settings: General: Permissions: Groups: Contributors/Readers/etc...

Who will receive an email when I change the name of the Project?

Comment: the full list of users from your second group will be notified. renaming a project changes its urls so people need to know where to find the project in future. Teams represent subsets of users (you can have multiple project teams, and users that are not team members but that are provided rights on the project).  Teams are about more than just Security (they are used in the Boards extensively for areas and iterations and resource planning).

Comment: @FrankThomas If I remove a user from a group, will they be emailed as well?  And if I add back into the group? I could remove them and add them if not so they don't recieve the email, the Project is not fully turned up so the project rename is unimportant at this point

Comment: well, its ALL groups. if you remove a user from ALL groups (including the team), they will no longer have access to the project at all, and will not be notified. if they exist in any of the groups or the team however they will get an email. also, review any org level groups that confer project level rights (like Team Collection Administrators) as those people will likely be notified as well.

Answer (score 0):

To see the full list of users, you may to `Settings->Permissions->Users` in your project:

[image]